# How to fix Runtime Error "91" in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have created a userform to enter data into worksheets for me. I am trying to code it where it will put the information into a selected worksheet. I have a combobox where I can select the sheet I want it to put the info in. I am trying to set the variable ws to the combobox value and I get a runtime error '91' and it says "object variable or with block not set". The code I am having problems with is below.

```
Private Sub bttn_Submit_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

'set the variable for the worksheet
ws = ComboBox1.Value

'find first empty row in database
iRow = Columns("A").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1



'check for a date
If Trim(Me.txt_Date.Value) = "" Then
  Me.txt_Date.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter a Date"
  Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="password"
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txt_Date.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txt_Invoice.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txt_Mileage.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.CheckBox_Oil_Filter
  .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.CheckBox_Air_Filter
  .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.CheckBox_Primary_Fuel_Filter
  .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.CheckBox_Secondary_Fuel_Filter
  .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Me.CheckBox_Transmission_Filter
  .Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Me.CheckBox_Transmission_Service
  .Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Me.CheckBox_Wiper_Blades
  .Cells(iRow, 19).Value = Me.CheckBox_Rotation_Rotated
  .Cells(iRow, 21).Value = Me.CheckBox_New_Tires
  .Cells(iRow, 23).Value = Me.CheckBox_Differential_Service
  .Cells(iRow, 25).Value = Me.CheckBox_Battery_Replacement
  .Cells(iRow, 27).Value = Me.CheckBox_Belts
  .Cells(iRow, 29).Value = Me.CheckBox_Lubricate_Chassis
  .Cells(iRow, 30).Value = Me.CheckBox_Brake_Fluid
  .Cells(iRow, 31).Value = Me.CheckBox_Coolant_Check
  .Cells(iRow, 32).Value = Me.CheckBox_Power_Steering_Check
  .Cells(iRow, 33).Value = Me.CheckBox_A_Transmission_Check
  .Cells(iRow, 34).Value = Me.CheckBox_Washer_Fluid_Check


'  .Protect Password:="password"
End With

'clear the data
Me.txt_Date.Value = ""
Me.txt_Invoice.Value = ""
Me.txt_Mileage.Value = ""
Me.txt_Date.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: `ws` is a worksheet.  `ComboBox1.Value` is a string.  You cannot set a worksheet to a string.  Do you want `Set ws = Worksheets(ComboBox1.value)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take your piece of code and explain you the inconsistency:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
ws = ComboBox1.Value
```

The first line of code is declaring `ws` as a Worksheet object. Objects in VBA need the keyword `Set` to be set, and of course the data type needs to match the declaration.

On the other hand, in the second statement you're setting `ws` as `ComboBox1.Value`, which is a type `String`. So:

1) The reason why you get the error is that `ws` is a variable that, because of its declaration, expects to get a `Worksheet` object but you're instead trying to cast a `String` in it;

2) What you probably want to do is to *have in `ws` the Worksheet object whose name is the `ComboBox1.Value`*; this, in terms of code, should be written as follows:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ComboBox1.Value)
```

You only need to replace the line `ws = ComboBox1.Value` with the line above.

Pay attention, in general: if you declare a variable of type *X*, it will always be able to cast only a *type X* object, unless you don't declare it at all (very bad practice, you would get errors after).

Comment: I would really like to know the reason of the downvote.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It fixed my problem. I am learning as I go and your explanation helped me very much!